# Insert selected image from wpf datagrid into mysql database

Tags: mysql, wpf

I am using DataGrid in WPF. I want to insert selected image from datagrid(in wpf) into mysql. Can you show some example codes, please?

Comment: Add some code to show what you do

Comment: Good thing that you asked. You shouldn't do this. Just save the file to file system and save the link to db.